# Update Wordpress Plugins from external script?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that xmlrcp on Wordpress is great for posting new posts, etc. But i have not found a way to for example help me manage a big network of blogs when it comes to updating plugins.

Anyone know how this could be achieved?

I am looking to build a "Dashboard" where i can control all the Wordpress installations from and one important part of that is to be able to update/add plugins.

Any help is very welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your looking for something like [managewp.](https://managewp.com/)

ITs not free but it works really well and seems to be exactly what youre looking for.